# Atom will not autocomplete closed quotes when typing f-strings

Tags: python, atom-editor, quotation-marks

I'm using the Atom editor as I make my way through *Learn Python the Hard Way*.

For some reason, Atom will autogenerate closed quotes in a basic string.

```
x = "There are 10 types of people."
```

But it will not when the string starts with f.

```
x = f"There are {types_of_people} types of people.
```

When I get to the end of the f-string, I have to add the closed quotes manually, which actually generates a new set of both open and closed quotes.

```
x = f"There are {types_of_people} types of people.""
```

I then have to delete one set of quotes to make the f-string work, which is not a big deal but annoying.

I've tried putting a space between the f and the open quotes.  Doing so generates the closed quotes but results in a coding error.

I haven't had this problem with the Sublime or Mu editors.  Any advice on how to fix it?

The following link has a suggested solution:

[F string autocomplete python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441647/f-string-autocomplete-python)

However, the solution is almost two years old. I'm wondering if there's a more recent fix that is less convoluted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [F string autocomplete python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441647/f-string-autocomplete-python)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  :)  It's my exact question.  I'm wondering though if there's a less convoluted resolution now.  That response was almost two years ago.